# Allow user to resize devexpress 14.1 Gridcontrol rows

Tags: c#, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm looking for a way to allow the user resize a single row height (during runtime off course) using the mouse, just like a table in MS Excel or Word. I can size the the columns can be re-sized when the grid have headers enabled.

I'm using devexpress 14.1 *Winforms* (not WPF) GridControl (framework 4 if it matters).

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, the GridView does not allow this.  If you are looking to resize ALL the rows, you can run the designer for the GridView and look under `OptionsCustomization`.  There will be a property called `AllowRowSizing`....set this to `True`.

There is a 'workaround' though, which can be found [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q450528) and [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2965), which should get you your desired results.